# How to parse LDAP Data Interchange Format string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ldif, dn

Say, I have a LDIF string as such: `CN=Subject Name, OU=Company, O=Subject Name, STREET=Main St, STREET=123, L=City, S=WA, PostalCode=98001, C=US`

Is there any framework method to parse it into its constituent components with C#?

Comment: This isn't a fully qualified domain name. This looks like [LDIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format).

Comment: @StevenV: You're right. I'll adjust the question...